# How can one turn off automatic frame interpolation in Meshcat.jl?

Tags: 3d, julia

I am using Meshcat.jl for 3d animations in Julia. When I try to animate an object with its position set to point A at frame t and point B at time t+1, Meshcat does some automatic interpolation so that the object appears to move continuously from A to B during animation. I looked at the source code of Meshcat.jl but couldn't figure out any way to turn off this automatic interpolation. I would really appreciate if someone can please suggest a solution or suggest any other Julia package for 3d animations where this problem doesn't arise.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the sliding motion, you should do the move within `atframe`:

```
atframe(anim, 0) do
    settransform!(vis[:cube], Translation(0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
end
```

If you want the object to appear only at time t at position 1 and only at time t2 at position 2, you may need to hide the object between t and t2.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using atframe for animation but it still interpolates position between consecutive frames.

Comment: So you want it to vanish and reappear later? you will have to do that manually. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Yes. At each frame I want the object to at positions that i am explicitly setting via atframe. If at frame 1, I set the position to be 0,0,0 and at frame 2, I set it to 10,0,0, then in the animation meshcat inserts additional "subframes" between frame 1 and 2 and  makes the object move continuously from x=0 to x=10, which I don't want.

Comment: Add new frame 2, manually, between frame 1 and 3 that removes the object.  Then put the object back in in frame 3 where you want it next.